# SharePoint online Public website to redirect to the custom domain name

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, redirect, domain, public-website

I want my SharePoint Online Public Website to redirect to the custom domain.After logging in to the Office 365 account, will i be able to edit the SharePoint Online Public website, or will the custom domain redirection will effect the edit part of website?

For eg. My sharepoint online public website "abc-public.sharepoint.com" should redirect to "www.abc.com" .How can i make this possible?

And also if the redirection is done and when i log in to the office 365 account using the link "abc-public.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"  will i be able to see the site contents?

Thanks ,

Avy

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way to redirect your public SharePoint site to another URL. Instead, you can manage DNS to make your public SharePoint site listen to requests for your domain - www.abc.com. Unfortunately this is not what you ask for.